# Is it possible to do serial port communication between android device that is connected by Bluetooth and Arduino that is connected by USB?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arduino

I am working on a project to develop VR-app.

So basically what I would like to do is to get the physiological data using Arduino that is connected to the PC by USB and get those data using VR-app that is installed on Quest 2 which is connected to the PC by Bluetooth then send those data to a server.

Ideally, I believe that connecting Arduino and Quest 2 either by Bluetooth or USB would be easier to implement but unfortunately, I don't have those adapter to do it.

What I am trying to figure out is how Quest 2 could access to serial port which Arduino is connected in order to retrieve the data.

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to host a local server on your PC, to which the Quest will connect (assuming they are on the same network). 
You can interpret Arduino sensor data in C# using [this](https://www.instructables.com/C-Serial-Communication-With-Arduino/) as a reference. That program can be extended to a web server with an endpoint /getSensorData. You can connect from Quest to that server with IP or maybe MDNS (I'm not sure that Quest suport that).